# How to keep bottom below content and sticky

Tags: html, css, footer

I am using below code.
 When I open the site,
footer is cover over the body content that fixed bottom side not below the contents. 
I need help two things. 
1) when Ctrl+ (-) zoom-out, footer should be fixed(sticky) bottom side
2) when Ctrl+ (+) zoom-in, footer should float over the body contents

I am not sure whether my explanation is told well or not.
Could you please help, how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

        <div id="header"> <?php     include 'header.php';   ?> </div>

        <div id="body"><div class="container0">     </div></div>

        <div id="footer"><?php  include 'footer.php';   ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
body {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      height:100%;
}

#container {
      min-height:100%;
      position:relative;
}

#body{
      padding:10px;
      padding-bottom:231px;
}

#footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 231px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried media query?

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px){ 
 #footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. But, footer width is decreased and still cover the contents.

Comment: Thanks. I was testing with not full wide browser, so it was decreased. Now I can see full wide screen. It works. Thanks. :-)

Comment: No problem. :D happy coding